# How to clear array from useState

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new comer in react-native. How do I clear this `useState` array?

```
const [tokenArray, setTokenArray]=useState([]);

// Need to Clear Array this line.
setTokenArray(tokenArray,[]);
  
var arraySize = responseJson.status.split(',').length;
for(var x=1;x<arraySize;x++){
    console.log("X--->"+x)
    setTokenArray(tokenArray => [...tokenArray, responseJson.status.split(',')[x]])
}
```

Comment: To clear an array, just do `setTokenArray([]);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a syntax error that you probably got by retyping the other `setTokenArray` call incorrectly:

```js
setTokenArray(tokenArray,[]);
```

should be

```js
setTokenArray([]);
// or
setTokenArray(tokenArray => []);
```

When you pass a function to `setTokenArray`, the first argument will be the old value of that variable. This is useful for when you need to mutate it like you do inside the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to clear out the array you can just set it to an empty array when calling `setTokenArray`.

```js
setTokenArray([]);
```